# IronPython Azure sending service bus message - assertion error

Tags: azure, ironpython

I've been trying different combination of strings to get this to work to no avail.  Hoping someone can help.  I am using the Azure SDK to send a Service Bus message.

```
GUID = '40100b19-1335-468d-bf18-fca6b15c8f0c'
Current_Lineup = '{"Flex": 11247, "DST": 530, "RB2": 9680, "RB1": 9448, "QB": 10699, "WR2": 9964, "WR3": 9427, "WR1": 11676, "TE": 11521}'
sbs = ServiceBusService('blahblah' , 'blahblahblah', 'owner')
msgbody = 'msg-body'
utf8msg = msgbody.encode('utf8')
bytemsg = bytes(utf8msg)
msg = Message(bytemsg, custom_properties={"MessageId":GUID,"Whitelist":Current_Lineup,"Type":"roster"})
## msg = Message(b'msg-body')
## msg = Message(b'msg-body', custom_properties={"MessageId":GUID,"Whitelist":Current_Lineup,"Type":"roster"})
sbs.send_topic_message('statustopic',msg)
```

Seems the Azure SDK doesn't like what I am sending for message body.  Using CPython works like a champ.  Using IronPython it dies with an AssertionError.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got it working, a bit of a kludge though.  Still would like a better solution so all you IronPython guys, chime in.

I change the message creation call to this...

```
msg = Message(None, custom_properties={"MessageId":GUID,"Whitelist":Current_Lineup,"Type":"roster"})
```

I don't need the body of the message to carry any of the data.  It's a lot easier to send data in the properties.

The only other thing I needed to change is comment this line in httpclient.py in send_request_body...

```
assert isinstance(request_body, bytes)
```

I would prefer to not hack the httpclient.py but that is the only way I could figure out how to get through this bug.